# Ubuntu に IPv6 接続したい

Tags: ubuntu, network, iptables

さくらインターネットで運用しているサーバーが IPv6 を受け入れていないことが判明して
受け入れるように設定中なのですがうまく行きません

https://manual.sakura.ad.jp/cloud/network/switch/ipv6.html#id3
こちらの設定を行って IPv6 アドレス自体は有効になりました

その後 ip6tables の設定が

```
ip6tables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

と何の設定もされていなかったので

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

という HTTPS だけ許可するルールを書いて

```
ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/iptables.rules.v6
```

を実行したところ
外部からの curl がタイムアウトから

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxxxxxxx port 443: Connection refused
```

に変わりました

IPv4 でアクセスすると nginx が応答するんですが
IPv6 でアクセスするにはこの状態からさらに何が足りないんでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginxの設定ファイルはどうなっていますか？たとえばserverディレクトリにlistenが

```
listen 443;
```

のみが存在していれば、

```
listen [::]:443;
```

のようなv6待受の設定が必要です。

Comment: その通りでした！　素早い回答ありがとうございます